# SEO impacts of new host

Tags: seo

How will the SEO be affected if I move a website to new host, the domain name will remain the same and old urls map to new ones. The owner wants to update some content (add and remove) on the new sites pages? Will adding content negatively affect the SEO of the pages?

Answer (score 3):

Changing the hosting generally doesn't have any significant impact on SEO.

If the new hosting will be more reliable with speed then it should be considered as a positive factor from SEO side.

Adding new pages with high-quality content should have a positive impact.

Just make sure the new host is not slow and new pages should have quality content and you should be fine.

Comment: Always choose a reasonable quality host. It does not have to be expensive. Just know that highly permissive and inexpensive hosts gain a reputation for low quality sites and being in good neighborhood is far superior to a bad one. It really does make a difference. Otherwise, it does not matter if you do your homework and choose a reasonable host. Cheers!!